# Disable Add new Item button from Edit in grid view

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I want a functionality where users can bulk edit the items in SharePoint list using Edit in grid view option but they can't add new item in the list from edit in grid view as i want them to add items only from PowerApps form.

Is it possible to hide the Add new item button from Edit in grid view?

Also is there a way to restrict users from adding duplicate values in SharePoint list based on a column?

Answer (score 0):

There is no SharePoint out of the box setting available to hide/disable "Add new Item" button at the bottom of list in "Edit in grid view" mode.

You can hide "New" option from command bar using JSON formatting:

```
{
  "commandBarProps" : {
    "commands": [
      {
        "key": "new",
        "hide": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Documentation**: [Command bar customization syntax reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-commandbar-formatting)

---

You can restrict users from adding duplicate values in SharePoint list based on a column value by setting the specific column as "Unique" column from column settings:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I dont want to show duplicates based on concatenated value of 3 columns. But in Concatenated columns we dont get this Enforce unique values option. How we can restrict users from entering same concatenated value as duplicate.

Comment: You cannot do it using SharePoint out of the box options, you have to manage it using formulas in Power apps customized forms.

Comment: Yes, we can use PowerApps but in that case if someone adds record from Grid View then that formula will not trigger.

Comment: I understood your concern but this is the limitation in SharePoint. In that case, you have to think about other approach like developing canvas application for bulk edit as well. Check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/create-update-records-bulk) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6yqIpjmPrs) for same.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the new button from command bar using PowerShell command if editing every view is not an option. Refer to -> https://sharepoint-tricks.com/hide-the-new-button-from-sharepoint-document-library/

Regarding hiding from grid view - this is not possible, however, you can disable the grid-view from library settings.